# How to open Camera view in Swift from Flutter code in order to access camera features such as AutoFocus

Tags: ios, swift, plugins, camera, flutter

I'm writing my app in Flutter with the Camera plugin. However, I find that I need the built-in camera features of iOS, such as auto-focus. For this purpose, I need use Swift. Is there a way to do this from Flutter or I have to re-write my app entirely in Swift? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use platform channels
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase

Also check out this example

https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/intro-to-platform-channels-building-an-image-picker-in-flutter-7e79c20065

Comment: Thank for the resource, just what I need.